# Как сделать чтобы функция возвращала все элементы при использовании цикла for?

Tags: python, функции

Помогите, как сделать чтобы функция возвращала все элементы при использовании цикла for?

```
a = ['ad','adwt',3,4,5,6,7]

def get(a):
    for i in a:
        return i

def main():
    print(get(a))

main()
```

Comment: Непонятно в каком виде функция должна выдавать вам элементы. Просто `a` вернёт вам все.

Answer (score 3):

Как на счет генераторов? Используйте yield вместо return чтобы функция возвращала генератор.

```
def get(a):
    for i in a:
        yield i
# get(a)
# <generator object ...>
```

Comment: + `print(*list(get(a)), sep='\n')`

Comment: @S.Nick. Можно без приведения к списку обойтись, просто распаковать. Так тоже работает при таком использовании

Answer (score 0):

```
a = ['ad','adwt',3,4,5,6,7]

def get(a):
    return '\n'.join([str(i) for i in a])

def main():
    print(get(a))

main()
```

---

Вывод:

> ```
> ad
> adwt
> 3
> 4
> 5
> 6
> 7
> ```

---

*Объяснение:*

```
[str(i) for i in a]
```

создает список элементов списка `a` переведенных в строки, и затем

```
'\n'.join([str(i) for i in a])
```

соединит все элементы этого списка в одну строку, но с символом `'\n'` между элементами списка.

Функция `print()` выведет эту строку — благодаря знаком `'\n'` - как элементы списка `a`, строку после строки.

---

Примечание:

Вместо

```
[str(i) for i in a]
```

возможно использовать стандартную функцию `map()`:

```
map(str, a)
```